# Can't login on intranet site keeps on asking for credentials ASP IIS MVC4

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, intranet

Problem Description: So basicly I had IIS express in visual studio 2012 set up and everything worked. It is an MVC 4 intranet application that uses windows authentication. I was able to login in to the intranet site I'm developing using my username and password. But when executing after entering some code the code was the following:

```
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
        Command getSnapIn = new Command("Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration");
        Command importSnapIn = new Command("import-module WebAdministration");
        Command getProcess = new Command("New-WebAppPool -Name test");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(getSnapIn);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(importSnapIn);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(getProcess);

        pipeline.Invoke();
        runSpace.Close();
```

It kept on asking for my credentials. I cannot see why this code would keep on triggering for credentials.
Things I tried already:

1. Commenting out the code
2. Setting up the site in IIS manager (still same problem)
3. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication
4. I Disabled Anonymous Authentication Enabled Windows Authentication. Went to providers and put NTML on top.
5. I did this in the web config file 
   `<system.web><authentication mode="Windows" />
   <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
   </system.web>`
6. I tried adding the site to internet explorer local sites.

Any Ideas about this?

Comment: This is an asp.net question - nothing to do with Classic

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861
Its fixed
Method 2 did the trick.